# Closing Jform in the constructor

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, swingx, jform

I am having a minor issue with the code. I just want the Jform to not be displayed if a condition is not met in the constructor portion of the form.Outside the constructor the dispose(), return and setVisible(false) all work fine. I have tried this.dispose(); and return; and this.setVisible(false); but the form is still displayed. With System.exit(0); it closes the complete app. Would really appreciate if someone can help me with this.

```
public class OrderGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public OrderGUI(Customer cust, Date dt, Time t) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    this();
if(condition)
{
/////do not initialize the Jform
}else{//// run rest of the code}
}
```

Comment: *"Closing Jform.."*  There is no such class in the J2SE API.  Don't talk like your IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do something like this

```
public class OrderGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public OrderGUI(Customer cust, Date dt, Time t) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
       this();
    }

   @Override
   public void setVisible(boolean val){
       if(!condition){
           super.setVisible(val);
       } 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Subash pointed it out, this works perfectly.

```
public class OrderGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public OrderGUI(Customer cust, Date dt, Time t) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
   this();
}

@Override
public void setVisible(boolean val){
   if(!condition){
       super.setVisible(val);
   } 
}
}
```